# flex localization equals character

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm having problems placing an equals character in my locale file

I have to do something like this:

```
#greater value

greater_value = the value must be ( >= ) than the corresponding value
```

but when the thing is displayed in the ui the text after the second equals is missed

how do you place an equals character in a flex locale file?

edit: I have already used, escape characters, ascci code, html codes and unicode unicodes.

Comment: Have you tried using a different separator? [`You can use an equals sign, a colon, or whitespace to separate the key from the value; for example:...`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_3.html#159863)

Comment: Yes, I have tried using the different separators, and the issue still happens, I dont know, it just happen with the equals character.

Comment: There is a little bit tricky way to overcome this problem:
greater_value = the value must be ( {0} ) than the corresponding value 
Then in your AS code, use StringUtil.substitute(localeString, ">=");

Comment: Does the "equals" sign really need to be localized?

Answer (score 2):

You can use unicode character representation:

```
greater_value = the value must be ( >\u003D ) than the corresponding value
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but the unicode representation didnt work for me, what I finally did was to use the solution proposed by harry ninh, using the StringUtil.substitute.

> There is a little bit tricky way to overcome this problem:
>
> greater_value = the value must be ( {0} ) than the corresponding value
>
> Then in your AS code, use StringUtil.substitute(localeString, ">=");